# Smoothing edges on an Ico Sphere and avoid artifacts when smooth shading

Tags: modeling, artifacts, smooth

I want to model a smoothed Icosphere (a D20 Dice) but I have artifacts/ unwanted hard edges.

[image]

You can see the Star shape (*) all around the dice. The triangles appear completely flat, which makes sense, but doesn't blend into the beveled edges like I would expect it. I tried subdividing or insetting the Triangle areas, which didn't help. I tried a few things but don't really know how the topology has to be. Maybe it's solvable using weighted normals or a different profile, but my knowledge is really thin on that topic.

Can you give me tips on how to get this model clean and smooth?

Comment: did you try harden normals and check autosmooth? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFipN.png

Comment: @Chris, Thank you. The edge looks good, but the corner doesn't blend in correctly.